# HREF with https link in a frame doesn't work

Tags: html, https, hyperlink, href

I created a page divided in 3 frames, the code is:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<frameset rows="100,*">
  <frame src="title.html" name="title" noresize="noresize">
  <frameset cols="100,*" noresize="noresize">
     <frame src="index.html" name="index">
     <frame src="body.php" name="body">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

In the index frame i want to insert a link to a https page (e.g. https://www.google.it/) that opens in the frame body, but when the link is clicked it opens nothing.
Here is the code of the index frame:

```html
<html>

<a href="https://www.google.it/" target="body">Google</a>

</html>
```

I tried with links that don't use https protocol and it works,so i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Are you calling it from a page served in https? why use frame?

Comment: Just an FYI, the `<frame>` tag is not supported any longer for HTML5. Use `<iframe>`.

Comment: 1)I think not. I use apache server, but i don't know what protocol is used 2)I use a frame because i need to open the link without exit the home(sorry for the english i'm italian)

Comment: already tried iframes but same problem